# VueJS exact-active-class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a menu using Router-link, and i want to put class "Active" on "li" when the Router-link was actived.

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level">
    <li v-for="item in menu">
        <router-link :to="{ name: somewhere }" tag="a" exact-active-class="IS-ACTIVATED">
            {{Name}}
        </router-link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to set a class to parent using "exact-active-class"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `v-if` to check which route you're in and add class if `$route.name` is `somewhere`

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level">
     <li v-for="item in menu" :class="{ 'IS-ACTIVATED': $route.name === somewhere }">
         <router-link :to="{ name: somewhere }">
             {{Name}}
         </router-link>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what i want !! =)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this might be:

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level">
  <router-link :to="{ name: somewhere }" tag="li" exact-active-class="IS-ACTIVATED">
            {{Name}}
  </router-link>
</ul>
```

Otherwise, no, you can't set it on a parent. I would recommend adapting your CSS instead. Also, you don't need to specify tag on router-link, it defaults to "a".

Comment: Hmmm it did not work, i have to click on "a" element. And it takes "router-link-exact-active" class.

Comment: Oh so you're saying it has to be an anchor element, e.g. "a"?

Comment: actually no... I just want to know if there is a way to put "IS-ACTIVATED" class on parent element ( li ) by the current router view selected.

Comment: `exact-active-class` only works on a router-link component. It will not work on its parent element.