# Vuejs active router link does not work, tried multipled ways

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, routerlinkactive

I cannot make the active button (router-link tag) to light up.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="bottom-buttons">                                          
 <span v-for="button in buttons" class="button" :class="{ 'is-active': $route.path === button.path}">
  <router-link :to="button.path">
   <i :class="button.iclass"></i>
    <p class="button-label">{{button.label}}  </p> 
  </router-link>
 </span>                                                                
</div>
```

When I print out `$route.path` it returns the right path, and `button.path` is the data I have in the data object, and it works. So the condition should be right. But the `'is-active'` class is not activated. (This thread: [VueJS exact-active-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365938/vuejs-exact-active-class))

If I hard-code the `'is-active'` class, it works.

When I use `a:hover, a:visited, a:link` it works, but `a:active` does not work :D. I have tried `a:router-link-active` but it does not work. (This thread: [How to VueJS router-link active style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083220/how-to-vuejs-router-link-active-style))

I have tried to add `linkActiveClass: 'is-active'` in the `/router/index.js` file as suggested. It does not work. (This thread: [Bulma navbar and VueJS router active link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173297/bulma-navbar-and-vuejs-router-active-link))

Anybody knows why? Or have more suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does your `is-active` class look like? Does it override existing styles?

Comment: ```.is-active { color: green }``` If I hardcode it the class works.

Comment: Try to change it to `.is-active { color: green !important; }`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code except you keep buttons as `span` instead of `router-link` with `tag="button"`

Comment: yes, that works !!! with ```!important``` and ```v-for``` on ```router-link``` :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that your problem is in the class condition. Maybe try to use `==` instead of `===` in your `:class`?

I would have add a comment instead of an answear if i had enough reputation :)

Comment: Try to put the button span inside the ```router-link``` tag and the ```v-for``` on the ```router-link```. Let me know.